# Java | Operator

Tags: java, operators

I have this question in my beginner Java programming class and I can't find in my book what a single '|' means as an operator.

The question is:

```
int j = 0;    
if ((8 > 4) | (j++ == 7))
    System.out.println("j = " + j);
```

Is j = 1?

Explain why.

The book explains the OR operator "||" with examples but it doesn't show this single "|". Does the meaning of the operator change between the two?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: It is a bitwise or operator http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: @JorgeZuverza, Why have you posted a link to a c++ site?

Comment: Look harder, or get a better book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the meaning changes, `||` is the logical `or` operator, while `|` is the bitwise `or`.

Since this operator operates (...) at the bit level, it doesn't short circuit the same way as `||`, meaning, even if the first operand is `true`, the second operand will be evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `||` and `&&` forms, rather than the `|` and `&` forms of these operators, Java will not bother to evaluate the right-hand operand alone.

```
Boolean b = true;
if(b || foo.test())
{
   //we entered without calling test()
}

if(b | foo.test())
{
   //we entered  calling test()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` -> This is bit-wise OR operator performs a bitwise inclusive OR operation and perform the both operand(right and left).

> The bitwise OR "|" operator produces 1 if either one or both of the
>   bits in its operands are 1. However, if both of the bits are 0 then
>   this operator produces 0. To be more precise OR "|" operator returns 1
>   in all cases except when both the bits of both the operands are 0.

```
if ((8 > 4) | (j++ == 7)) System.out.println("j = " + j);
```

Here `8>4` will return `true` and `j++ == 7` will return `false`. so it will be `if(true|false)` and here bit-wise operator will return `true` or 1 and print value of j which became 1 after j++.

Comment: It is also the (non-shorthand) `OR` conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

The `|` operator is bitwise OR, but you may ask why would someone use the bitwise OR on boolean variables?

Logical OR operator (`||`) has a feature called short-circuiting, which means that if the left operand evaluates to `true`, no further processing is done, and the right hand operand even will not *evaluate*. But bitwise OR operator `|` always evaluates both operands, and if applied on boolean operands, evaluates both of them and then applies a simple or on the results.

In your case, `(j++ == 7)` is always evaluated, regardless of the result of `8 > 4`. This does not happen with `||` operator. So `j` will be incremented by one and the output of the program is `1`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is No because j is initialized at 0 but is never assigned after this. So the value of j stays at 0 for the whole time.

Comment: but in the right-hand side of the operator, doesn't j++ add 1 to the initialized number?

Comment: (j++ == 7) evaluates if j++ = 7 but it does not increment j. To increment j you should have seen j = j++; ( == means evaluation while = means assignation)

Comment: Try it in a small java application (right in the main function). You will see that j is never incremented.

Comment: Simon, your statement is incorrect. j++ is an in-place increment of j, meaning, it's equivalent to j=j+1 or j+=1. There is a difference between ++j and j++, but that is besides the point here, since it has no influence in this case.